# Find electric field due to point charge +Q under given condition

Tags: electric-field

As shown in the image, there are four conditions given:

Electric field in figure:1 at point 'P' let = **E**_P,
Electric field in figure:2 at point 'M' let = **E**_M,
Electric field in figure:3 at point 'R' let = **E**_R,
Electric field in figure:4 at point 'S' let = **E**_S,

we can say: **E**_P < **E**_M
but
**E**_P = **E**_R {why}
and
**E**_R < **E**_S
[image]

Comment: This would be more appropriate on the [physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interior surface of the symmetric conductive sphere around the point charge is an equipotential surface. It causes nothing between the charge and the surface. The electric flux (=Q) only stops to the surface. The charge distribution on the inner surface is uniform. It cannot cause any field to the interior space, the only effective cause of the electric field is the +Q. The exact proof needs some vector integration math. It can be found in the web and Physics textbooks. See the Addendum.

The others get some surface charge which is negative at the side of your point charge +Q. That negative charge generates some electric field to the space and that field is at least partially to the same direction as the field generated by your point charge+Q. Thus the total field between +Q and the conductor is stronger than the field generated by +Q alone.

ADDENDUM:

I claimed that the uniformly distributed charge -Q on the inside surface of the conductive sphere doesn't make any field inside the sphere cavity. There's no trivial proof for it, but the situation has exact analogy with gravity inside of hollow spherical shell.

The analogy is uniform distribution of mass and the same 1/(R^2) distance law.

In Physics textbooks the zero gravity at every point inside the spherical shell is proved by showing that every point get the same gravity attraction to opposite directions when the total effect is integrated over the sphere. Here is one full calculation of it: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/sphshell2.html

That proof is the hard workers way, I think. The wanted thing Ep=Er can be reasoned indirectly. Imagine a spherical surface wit radius r around the point charge +Q. The total flux through that surface should be +Q because there's no other charge inside. If we believe the field between the point charge +Q and the -Q on the inner sphere is symmetric Er should be perpendicular with the imagined sphere and have the same flux density +Q/the area of the sphere. But that's the same as the +Q would generate in free space.

Comment: As you said-[The charge distribution on the inner surface is uniform. It cannot cause any field to the interior space, the only effective cause of the electric field is the +Q.], charge distribution on the inner surface will be uniform and -Q in amount. Outer surface charge distribution will be uniform and +Q in amount. Even -Q distribution on the inner side is uniform but how can we say that it won't create any electric field inside the sphere, there is symmetry only on the centre of the spherical shell So there(at center) can be zero electric field due to -Q.  So why E_P = E_R

Comment: Minus Q uniformly distributed on the inner sphere surface causes zero field at any interior point. But there's still the field vaused by +Q. I will show later a proof for the zero field of minus Q.